# Unresolved reference: 'Httpresponse' error in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, import

`demo.py`:

```py
from django.http import Httpresponse

def index(request) :
    return Httpresponse("Hello")
```

I am checking `HttpResponse`, `HTTPResponse` instead of `Httpresponse`, but I couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: The correct import is `from django.http import HttpResponse` likewise the return statement should be `return HttpResponse("Hello")`.

Answer (score 0):

From `django.http` import `HttpResponse`:

```
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello")
```

This is the correct syntax.